# Why am I allowed to set end() for std::vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector

In the standard library implementation of `end()` I am able to set the past-the-end value in addition to being able to retrieve it. Why is this allowed? Won't this potentially lead to issues?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    *v.end() = 2;    // why am I allowed to do this?
    std::cout << *v.end() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "allowed".

Comment: Read this: [What is Undefined Behavior?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Become familiar with it, because you're invoking it.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this allowed?

It isn't. You are invoking [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This code may do anything, including crashing and printing 2.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allowed to do that. Just because your program doesn't crash doesn't mean it's allowed. Maybe your program will crash on Tuesday when you show it to your boss. Or maybe you wrote 2 to some other variable.

This is called *undefined behaviour*, and it means that you can't expect anything in particular to happen - you can't even expect a crash.

Answer (score 0):

This will *definitely* lead to issues and is not allowed by the standard (undefined behavior). Unfortunately it's not possible to write a compiler that diagnoses every possible violation of the standard so some code constructs like this will compile even though they are illegal as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: In this case it's not really like it's not possible, it's that it slows down stuff. Every standard library implementation I used has some debug mode that can detect this kind of issue without problems, but it slows down significantly the generated code.